# creating DB and grant syntax error in mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-grant, mysql-8.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjK0g.png)I'm beginner python code, and not good at english.

my laptop window 10 pro, python version 3.6 mysql commmunity server version 8.0.12

problem

headfirst python

this is the code

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql>create database vsearchlogDB;
mysql>grant all on vsearchlogDB.* to 'vsearch' identified by 'vsearchpasswd';
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'vsearchpasswd'' at line 1

Comment: `create user vsearchlogDB identified by  'vsearchpasswd';` not just `create vsearchlogDB;`

Answer (score 2):

it should be grant `all privileges`, not just `all` the username should also have the host pointer like `vserach'@'%'

```
grant all privileges on vsearchlogDB.* to 'vsearch'@'%' identified by 'vsearchpasswd';
```

is more like it

EDIT: I'm blind and totally ignored the "8.0" part. On 8.0 this should look like:

```
create user 'vsearch'@'%' identified by 'vsearchpasswd';
grant all privileges on vsearchlogDB.* to 'vsearch'@'%'; //(Don't forget the ';')
```

Comment: same error occurred        ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'vsearchpasswd'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this code:**

```
create user 'vsearch' identified by 'vsearchpasswd';

grant all on vsearchlogDB.* to vsearch;
```

Comment: How is this better than the previous answer?